# Throw HttpException at service in nestjs

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, nestjs

Is it good way to throw Http Exeption at service in nestjs?
What is the best way to processing error at service in nestjs?

Comment: Services should contain the business logic of your application. So there should be meaningful errors thrown. This can be mapped onto an HTTP Error in the controller layer. But in the end, you can decide how to structure your own backend. If your usecase is fine with throwing HTTP exceptions in the service layer you do no harm to anybody.

Comment: Thanks for answer

Comment: I asked myself same question, and in my opinion throwing http exceptions in services does not seems to be right. HTTP exceptions are related to controllers, so they need to be used in controller. Services are reusable piece of code which can be called beside controllers, and in some cases may cause unexpected behaviour.

Comment: You are right.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From experience, it's best practice to throw HTTPExceptions in the controller logic manually or have an exception filter automatically catch exceptions. Services should be reusable pieces of functionality that can sometimes be used in non-http contexts.

Having http logic in the service layer feels like an anti-pattern.

Answer (score 1):

To elaborate on this answer, https://stackoverflow.com/a/73211663/1500042, you can use it to automatically configure http codes:

my.controller.ts:

```
@Get()
async getIt(@Req() req) {
try {
  return await this.myService.getThe(req.thing);
} catch (error) {
  throw new HttpException(error.message, HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
}
```

This sends a '400' response and blames the user (as you do). As a bonus it resists crashing on bad requests.